# Ajax call to php not found, 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to build my own WordPress theme and it seems to work but I'm having problems with my email form. The code worked when I used it before adapting to WordPress but now it doesn't.

```
$(function() {
$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        // Prevent spam click and default submit behaviour
        $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log ('1');

        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message

        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            console.log ('2');
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "./mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Enable button & show success message
                console.log ('3');

                $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');
```

The JavaScript file is in this route: `domain/wp-content/themes/federo/js/contact_me.js`

And the PHP file is here: `domain/wp-content/themes/federo/mail/contact_me.php`

Comment: It just doesn't found the page. You should try with this:  `../mail/contact_me.php`

Comment: I was thinking wrong. I meant: What happens if you replace the URL with: `"/wp-content/themes/federo/mail/contact_me.php"`

Comment: Many thanks!!! It worked, I feel like a stupid but your help has been great

Answer (score 3):

Even though @ruslan-nigmatulin answer will work, it's better to pass that URL (and any other things you need) [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) function, like so:

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/mail/contact_me.php');
```

In this example:
- `ajax-script` is the handle you've used with `wp_enqueue_script`
- `ajax_object` is the name of the object that will be available to your script
- 3rd paramater is an array of values you'd like to pass

Then to get your `ajax_url` in JS, you will simply do `ajax_object.ajax_url`. In this case (assuming federo is your current theme), `ajax_object.ajax_url` will be `http://domain/wp-content/themes/federo/mail/contact_me.php`

Comment: Wp gives you the function so use it to the full potential so in the future you do not need to change all the URL in your js. Just change the URL in the function.

Comment: Many many thanks for worrying, at thins moment I tried the previous solution and worked, so I'm going to try yours in order of improving my skills in this themes. Many thanks to you too for helping, I really apreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
url: "./mail/contact_me.php",
```

into absolute path

```
url: "http://domain/wp-content/themes/federo/mail/contact_me.php",
```